# Dynamically selecting cells in Excel Worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a calendar of months. The user can select a year for the month they want. When a user selects to create a month, I want to select all the weekdays in that month and give it a named range. How can I select a range of cells for a selected month and year and give it a named range?

Here is the recorded macro (for Jan 2016), but I'm not sure how to create this programmatically. I cannot reuse it because what if the user picks a different month or year, then I won't know which row columns contain weekdays.

```
range( _
    "C9:D9,E9:F9,G9:H9,I9:J9,K9:L9,C11:D11,E11:F11,G11:H11,I11:J11,K11:L11,C13:D13,E13:F13,G13:H13,I13:J13,K13:L13,C15:D15,E15:F15,G15:H15,I15:J15,K15:L15,C17:D17,E17:F17" _
    ).Select
range("E17").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Test", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=PTO!R9C3,PTO!R9C5,PTO!R9C7,PTO!R9C9,PTO!R9C11,PTO!R11C3,PTO!R11C5,PTO!R11C7,PTO!R11C9,PTO!R11C11,PTO!R13C3,PTO!R13C5,PTO!R13C7,PTO!R13C9,PTO!R13C11,PTO!R15C3,PTO!R15C5,PTO!R15C7,PTO!R15C9,PTO!R15C11,PTO!R17C3,PTO!R17C5"
```

----My Code Example----

```
For x = 1 to 42
    ' Determine where the 1st day falls
    ' Is it a weekday? Add my coordinates to an array so I can create a named range later.
Next x

CreateNamedRange(weekdayArray)
```

[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of (a portion) of your workbook to see how your sheet is organized.

Comment: Not sure I understand your request. When the user presses a button on one sheet, I create a new sheet and then starting at A3, I put a number representing a date for the month I am on. So, if the 1st day of the month starts on a Friday, I move over 6 columns and put a one and then a 2 on the next column (Saturday). Then on the next row down, A4 (Sunday), I put a 3 and so on. Does that help?

Comment: I've added to my question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign selected range into variable `Test`, you can use following command:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Test", RefersTo:="=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Selection.Address
```

It is impossible for us to help you with selecting some particular cells based on another cell is selcted, without further information about structure of your workbook.

Comment: I've added to my question. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, please tell me, how program would now which days should be in this named range, and which not?

Comment: All weekdays should be in the named range.

Comment: In this `weekdayArray` array, right? Can you tell something more about it? Some example of values inside? Value type is `Date`, `String`, or maybe `Integer`?

Comment: The values in the weekdayArray are strings of coordinates that correspond to where the weekday is located (9,1; 9,3; 9,5...). If you look at the image in my question, I will create a month the user selects from a dropdown. Then, after creating the month, I want to select all the weekdays (I highlighted gray for this question) and give it a named range.